# javascript csv strip out lines of all commas

Tags: javascript, regex

All,

I am thinking the fastest way to strip out lines of all commas in a csv is with a reg expression, correct?

If I have a file like this

```
jon,lastname,1/1/1970
bob,lastname,1/1/1970
sally,lastname,1/1/1970
,,,
,,,
anne,smith,1/1/1970
,,,
```

What is the fastest way in javascript to strip out lines with just commas?

I have tried a bunch of different approaches in javascript and no luck.  My thinking is test anything from start of line and look for multiple instances of commas or newlines.  When I try it everything comes back true

```
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        console.log('test', /^([,\n]*)/.test(rows[i]));
    }
```

Thx
jonpfl

Comment: For regular expression experimentation it's often wise to first visit [regex101.com](http://regex101.com); in this instance I'll link you to an explanation of your posted regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/oTXdir/2

Comment: how about this one `^[,]+$`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will help,

```js
const input = `
jon,lastname,1/1/1970
bob,lastname,1/1/1970
sally,lastname,1/1/1970
,,,
,,,
anne,smith,1/1/1970
,,,
`;

const lines = input.trim().split(/\n/);
const cleaned_lines = lines.filter(i => !/^[,]+$/.test(i)).join('\n');

console.log(cleaned_lines);
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but curious why 'm' is needed?